# Hibernate JPA Cannot Create due to FK

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

When I try to create a new category in my application I am getting the below error which is complaining about a FK constraint.   However the FK it is complaining about maps the Category Description to the Category, since both are being created at the same time I am not sure why this is having an issue.

I can update Categories and category descriptions without issue.

Error

```
ERROR - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`crcart3`.`categorydescription`, CONSTRAINT `FKC6C4CBFE6FD28044` FOREIGN KEY (`category_description_id`) REFERENCES `categorydescription` (`category_id`))
```

Category Table

```
@Table(name = "Category")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "ImageMapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "image_id")
    )
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Image categoryImageId;

    @JoinTable(
            name="CategoryDescription",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="category_description_id")
    )
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private CategoryDescription categoryDescription;

    @JoinTable(
            name = "CategoryMapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
    )
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Category parentCategory;

    @Column(name = "category_sort_order")
    private int sortOrder;

    @Column(name = "date_added")
    private Timestamp dateAdded;

    @Column(name = "last_modified")
    private Timestamp lastModified;
```

Category Description Table

```
@Table(name="CategoryDescription")
public class CategoryDescription {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_description_id")
    private int categoryDescriptionId;

    @Column(name="category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="language_id")
    private Language languageId;

    @Column(name="category_name")
    private String categoryName;

    @Column(name="category_text")
    private String categoryText;
```

Comment: And the code which causes this exception is?

Comment: Its an insert with null categoryId and a parentCategory.categoryId of 1

Comment: That's a *description* of the code. The bug is caused by the code, so the code matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says:

```
(`crcart3`.`categorydescription`, 
 CONSTRAINT `FKC6C4CBFE6FD28044` FOREIGN KEY (`category_description_id`) 
 REFERENCES `categorydescription` (`category_id`))
```

This means that in the table `categorydescription`, the column `category_description_id` is a foreign key to the column `category_id` of the *same* table `categorydescription`.

This doesn't look right to me. It doesn't even seem right to have a `category_id` column in this table.

Comment: the FK should be a reference to the category_id column in the category table. At least that is my understanding of the join in the categories entity.

Comment: Ouch. I just noticed that the same table (CategoryDescription) is also used as a join table between Category and ... CategoryDescription. That is also wrong.